# What a variable defined in print function does?

Tags: python

It looks as a variable is being declared in print but when I run it behave differently noticing is not a variable so what **end='  '** means and does?

[image]

Comment: It is a keyword argument to the [print function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

Comment: functions in python can take position arguments (args) and keyword arguments (kwargs). The documentation for the print function is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Comment: print new line simple

Answer (score 0):

The **print** method can take multiple variables which is what you're doing here. `end` is a named param for the print method that tells it what to print at the end of the given string. So yes, it is a variable being declared as an empty string. Other variables that print takes are:

- sep
- file
- flush

See more in the documentation here: [w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_print.asp#:%7E:text=Definition%20and%20Usage,before%20written%20to%20the%20screen)